# Is it possible to run GoogleTV emulator for ARM?

Tags: android, android-emulator, arm, google-tv, kvm

[GoogleTV emulator](https://developers.google.com/tv/android/docs/gtv_emulator) for x86 uses [KVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel-based_Virtual_Machine). For creating GoogleTV AVDs, Google says "*The CPU type is automatically set to Intel Atom (x86) and can't be changed.*"

Is it possible to run GoogleTV emulator for ARM? Google says that "*KVM emulation is not available for ARM-based AVDs*", but is it (nevertheless) still possible to run the GoogleTV ARM-emulator? If yes, how does it get rid of KVM issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GoogleTV emulator doesn't support ARM based AVD's.

Comment: Thanks Bhavya for the feedback. And GTV x86 emulator still can not be run on Windows, correct?

Comment: one more question - what are the missing pieces to have ARM emulator for GoogleTV? Will you be able to avoid KVM dependency?

Comment: Google TV emulator requires Linux with KVM.No support for Windows and Mac OS at the moment.Please open a feature request for avoiding KVM dependency and we will follow up with Engineering/Product team.

Comment: ARM emulator would be run on x86 host. Can you explain (very briefly) how the current KVM dependency prevents running emulator of ARM target system? Just give us a few lines on relationship between the emulator and the host in terms of ARM support (and what functionality would be blocked so it can not be done).

Answer (score 1):

Currently is not possible to run Google TV emulator without KVM.

In the Google TV issues tracker there is a topic related to [supporting to run the emulator in Windows/Mac computers](http://code.google.com/p/googletv-issues/issues/detail?id=28&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Type%20Status%20Summary).

You can star the issue in the Tracker to be notified about changes related to this issue.